# Verwendung von Präsens / Perfekt im Beispielsatz

Tags: tense, perfect-tense

Ich bin jüngst über einen Satz gestolpert, bei dem ich mir nicht ganz sicher bin, wie er korrekt geschrieben werden müsste. Der Satz lautet wie folgt:

> *Bereits bevor ein Gerät eingesetzt werden kann, müssen Prüfungen erfolgen / erfolgt sein, welche belegen, dass das Gerät allen Anforderungen genügt*

In welcher Zeitform muss das Wort *erfolgen* hier stehen? Im Originaltext war es im Präsens formuliert (*erfolgen*), ich hätte aber aus dem Bauch heraus getippt, dass stattdessen Perfekt verwendet werden müsste (*erfolgt sein*), da es sich hierbei relativ zum Einsatz des Gerätes um ein abgeschlossenes Ereignis handelt, dessen Ausgang für den Einsatz relevant ist. Zumal es auch mit alternativen Verben wie *erledigen* oder *bestehen* aus dem Sprachgefühl heraus immer nur im Perfekt korrekt klingt (auch wenn diese freilich die Satzaussage verhunzen).

Oder hat hier das Wort *bereits* irgendeinen Einfluss auf die Zeitform? Der Text stammt aus einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit.

Comment: Die Prüfungen müssen bereits _erfolgt sein_ um irgendetwas _zu belegen_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wenn du schon so spitzfindig sein willst (was die deutsche Sprache nicht ist), dann wenigstens ganz und gar: *Die Prüfungen müssen bereits erfolgt sein, um irgendetwas belegt zu haben*. Denn auch der Beleg muss abgeschlossen sein.

Comment: @tofro Na ja, das war ein Kommentar (nur so aus dem Bauch raus). Ansonsten hätte ich vielleicht eine Antwort geschrieben.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die deutsche Sprache ist bei Weitem nicht so pingelig wie andere (z.B. die englische), was die Zeitenfolge angeht. Dinge, die vorher passiert sind (oder, wie hier, passiert sein müssen), müssen nicht notwendigerweise mit einem vorzeitigen Tempus ausgedrückt sein.

Es gibt auch in der deutschen Grammatik (ebenfalls im Gegensatz zu z.B. dem Englischen) keinerlei feste Regeln (allenfals *[beschriebene Tendenzen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Tempora/Zeitfolge.html)*) zur Vor- bzw. Nachzeitigkeit und dem zugehörigen Tempus.

Solange das Verständnis gewährleistet ist bzw. aus dem Kontext heraus entsteht, ist die durchgängige Verwendung des Präsens hier durchaus angebracht, vor allem, wenn man anfängt, hier pingelig zu werden, sollte man auch ganz pingelig sein:

> Bereits bevor ein Gerät eingesetzt werden kann, müssen Prüfungen  erfolgt sein, welche belegten, dass das Gerät allen Anforderungen genügt hat.

Spätestens jetzt merkt man (alle Zeiten sachlich richtig, Dinge, die vorzeitig sind, sind mit einem "früheren" Tempus ausgedrückt), dass diese Zeitenfolge doch ziemlich gekünstelt, möglicherweise sogar sinnentstellend  wirkt (es ist nicht vollkommen klar, bzw. der Satz scheint so sogar in Frage zu stellen, ob das Gerät den Anforderungen immer noch gerecht wird, denn der Beweis dafür ist ja möglicherweise schon vor langer Zeit erbracht worden und war nur zum Zeitpunkt der Prüfung gültig).

Comment: Dass der letzte "pingeligste" Satz die Sache in Frage zu stellen scheint, beruht das auf die Präteritumform "belegte"? Übrigens danke für den Zuschuss meines Wortschatzes (pingelig)!

Comment: Ich würde dennoch sagen "belegen". Denn der Beleg ist in der Gegenwart (beim Einsatz) noch genauso gültig, wie als er erstellt wurde.